# How do I get the YouTube preview image to show up in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I realize there are a lot of YouTube in WebView questions but they don't seem to address my problem exactly.

I am loading a website with an embedded YouTube clip in a WebView, the problem is the YouTube preview image does not appear, I just get a black box with YouTube at the bottom.

This same website loads the preview image in the Android browser. The phone does not have Flash.
[image: Side by Side Screenshot]

I understand it cant play the video without flash, I don't want it to play in the WebView, I just need the preview to load like it does in the regular browser.

I cant edit the website itself but it seems to be using this for the YouTube video.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="271"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/28L-hOJHwUw?rel=0&amp;hd=1" width="475"></iframe></div>
```

I am enabling both Javascript and Plugins in my WebView.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewplan);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit:
Found out that it is throwing a js error so is anyone out there able to display a YouTube embed preview in a WebView without flash, Or is this simply not possible?

Error:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'a' [undefined] is not an object. -- 
From line 342 of http://s.ytimg.com/yt/jsbin/www-embed_core_module-vflcoqCCO.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube JS is probably either shutting things down because it does not detect Flash or having a an error. If it is having an error you can find out of these by [setting a custom WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebChromeClient%28android.webkit.WebChromeClient%29) and override its [onConsoleMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage%28android.webkit.ConsoleMessage%29) method. Pump this to your LogCat (do a JS alert) and you will know about errors at least.

Comment: Thanks there is an error, seems to be coming from the Youtube js file, no idea what to do with it though.                       TypeError: Result of expression 'a' [undefined] is not an object. -- 
From line 342 of http://s.ytimg.com/yt/jsbin/www-embed_core_module-vflcoqCCO.js